# Where can I find the classification of groups of order 16p?

Tags: reference-request, gr.group-theory, finite-groups

I need to classify the groups of order $16p$ by their generators and relations between the generators. Can I find this classification anywhere?

Comment: Related: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/790452/classify-the-nonabelian-groups-of-order-16p-where-p-is-a-prime-number

Comment: This appears to be a duplicate of a question on mathstackexchange as pointed out in the comments
http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/790452/classify-the-nonabelian-groups-of-order-16p-where-p-is-a-prime-number

Comment: I am **against** closing as a duplicate of something on **another** site. (I am not against closure itself but to close as a duplicate of a question on another site seems not somthing that should be done in my opinion.)

Comment: @quid, the duplicate at mse was migrated from MO if that makes a difference.

Comment: @BenjaminSteinberg Yes, I knew that. It does not make any difference in my opinion.

Comment: can you help me?

Comment: @quid, the op is in fact the OP of the migrated question as well.

Comment: @BenjaminSteinberg Oh. Now this escaped me. It is obviously inappropriate to repost the question here, then, and I just voted to close. Still I think that "Is a duplicate of question Q on math.SE" should not be used as the reason to close in general.

Comment: @quid, I agree in general. But to repost the same question without saying so is inappropriate.

Comment: @BenjaminSteinberg yes, certainly. I overlooked that fact. If not I likely would not have made this point here. Sorry for the confusion and thanks for pointing it out.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, the classification of groups of order $2^kp$ for $k \leq 8$ and arbitrary primes $p$
is included in the [GAP SmallGroups Library](http://www.gap-system.org/Packages/sgl.html).